# Microsoft Access database-form slow when form properties set to: "Edited records locked"

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an issue with a simple access database. through debugging I have isolated the issue to the specific forms record lock setting. I have a split database and a simple form accessing the data. When two users are connected at the same time the second user to connect suffers serious performance issues on the form. It does not matter who connects first, It is always the second user that has this performance hit. If I change record locks on the form to no locks then there is no problem. I, however, require the record locks.

The performance hit is purely when editing a record. Not on locked records either, the locks work correctly, but when the second user edits any non-locked record the edits take forever to load. simply ticking a check box takes 1 minute to complete (during this one minute the screen freezes). For user number-one this remains instantaneous.

I am using Microsoft access 2016. But have the same issue when I use 2013.

Any help on this head scratcher would be much appreciated!

Tom

Comment: Just to clarify a few things: both users have a local frontend? The backend is a standard .accdb on a network drive? Network speed is ok (not a WAN)?

Comment: Are you using page level or record level locking?

Comment: Thanks for your reply yes both users have a local front end. The network speed is excellent. And it does not change when on record level locking or page level

Comment: If it helps, the form is based on a query (stored in the front ends) that will return around 6 records. They are also standard accdb files.

Comment: I have had many similar performance issues. The general solution I have found it to open a linked table and keep it open, either programmatically or just open it in the UI (in your case you probably want to do it programmatically to avoid user confusion). There is an explanation somewhere of why that works (something about Access closing and opening the links for every transaction otherwise if I remember right), but the important thing from my experience is that it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a back end lock issue. I always maintain a persistent connection on my databases. The issue is entirely based on the record locks settings of the form. When I change to no locks the problem disappears. But I need record locks.